# Object with methods and own return

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying, without success, to do like in other languages which the object can have a default return value, but yet has its methods. Like:

```
var o = {
    this: "MyReturn",
    SampleString: "My String",
    MyMethod1: function() {},
    MyMethod2: function() {},
}
```

Then, my output should be:

```
> o
< "MyReturn"
> o.SampleString
< "My String"
> o.MyMethod1()
< function() {}
```

Is it possible to do? (In a way that doesn't use Prototype, or it will conflict with my code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as-such. `o` would always be an object. The closest you could come would be custom `toString` method and casting `o` to a string or making the object a `Function` and call `o` like `o()`.

Here are some option that get as close as JavaScript can get.

## Option 1: Making o a function object and calling it.

```
var o = function(){
  return "MyReturn";
};
o.SampleString = "My String";
o.MyMethod1 = function() {};
o.MyMethod2 = function() {};
```

**Output**

```
> o()
< "MyReturn"
> o.SampleString
< "My String"
> o.MyMethod1()
< function() {}
```

## Option 2: Custom toString method.

```
var o = {
    toString: function(){return "MyReturn";},
    SampleString: "My String",
    MyMethod1: function() {},
    MyMethod2: function() {},
}
```

**Output**

```
> String(o)
< "MyReturn"
> o.SampleString
< "My String"
> o.MyMethod1()
< function() {}
```

In this second option, `String(o)` can be substituted for `""+o`, `o.toString()`, or anthing that causes type-casting to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `toString()` method.

> Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.
>   **Source: [MDN Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)**

```
var o = {    
    SampleString: "My String",
    MyMethod1: function() {},
    MyMethod2: function() {}

};

o.toString = function () {
   return "MyReturn";
};

alert(o);
// MyReturn;

alert(o.SampleString);
// My String;

alert(o.MyMethod1);
// function () {}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GTQJT/)**

Comment: You might want to check the output on more time.

Comment: That is a pitty we have to use o.toString() to call the value, but it solves in parts.

Comment: alert !== console.log. And do you know why alert magically works?

Comment: @epascarello please enlighten me.

Comment: @TonyCamargo it will do that for all objects

Comment: `alert(o)` gonna work and output the string. `console.log(o)` no, it will output the object. This is because JavaScript is weakly typed and has a dynamic conversion with no specified types. Then, under all, alert converts your value to a string. An example is `var x = document.getElementById("id")`. `console.log(x)` will log `<div id="x"></div>`, but `alert(x)` gonna say `[object HTMLDivElement]`. It does a `alert(value.toString())` basically.

Comment: @JayHarris, It will not work for all the methods/functions. Some methods/functions deal with it like being an object, like `console.log()`. Some others deal with it by calling `.toString()` in a hidden way. That is `alert()`

Comment: @TonyCamargo lol I was being sarcastic, i know what it does, thats why overwriting the toString method work in this case. casting gets the job done in the console. `console.log(o +  ""); // MyString`. `console.log(o == "MyReturn"); // true` but the accepted answer's first answer is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest is this

```
 var o = {name:"myName"};    
 o.toString = function(){return o.name}    
 console.log(o+"");
```